# Create a new variable that counts the number of non-missing data columns in row by group

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I have a dataframe as follows:

| firmid | year | c1 | c2 | cn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | NA | 4 | text |
| 1 | 2001 | 3 | 2 | text |
| 1 | 2002 | NA | NA | NA |
| 1 | 2003 | 2 | 3 | NA |
| 1 | 2004 | NA | 8 | NA |

```
df <- data.frame(
  firmid = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004),
  c1 = c(NA, 3, NA, 2, NA),
  c2 = c(4, 2, NA, 3, 8),
  cn = c("text", "text", NA, NA, NA)
)
```

I want a new column that counts the number of non-missing data columns for a group (firmid, year) so I can get the following result. In my real dataset, I have 400+ columns and many firms across many years.

| firmid | year | c1 | c2 | cn | non-missing-columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | NA | 4 | text | 4 |
| 1 | 2001 | 3 | 2 | text | 5 |
| 1 | 2002 | NA | NA | NA | 2 |
| 1 | 2003 | 2 | 3 | NA | 4 |
| 1 | 2004 | NA | 8 | NA | 3 |

My failed attempt:

```
df %>%
group_by(firmid, year) %>%
mutate(non-missing-columns = sum(!is.na(.)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your example data in base R, simply:

```
df$non_missing_columns <- rowSums(!is.na(df))

#  firmid year c1 c2   cn non_missing_columns
#1      1 2000 NA  4 text                   4
#2      1 2001  3  2 text                   5
#3      1 2002 NA NA <NA>                   2
#4      1 2003  2  3 <NA>                   4
#5      1 2004 NA  8 <NA>                   3
```

However you mentioned you wanted to do it by group, grouping by both `firmid` and `year`. In your example data, you only have one observation by these groups. If we modify and extend your data to have multiple observations by group:

```
df <- data.frame(
  firmid = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  year = rep(c(2000, 2000, 2002, 2002, 2003), 2),
  c1 = c(NA, 3, NA, 2, NA, rep(NA, 5)),
  c2 = c(4, 2, NA, 3, 8, rep(NA, 5)),
  cn = c("text", "text", NA, NA, NA, rep(NA, 5))
)

#   firmid year c1 c2   cn
#1       1 2000 NA  4 text
#2       1 2000  3  2 text
#3       1 2002 NA NA <NA>
#4       1 2002  2  3 <NA>
#5       1 2003 NA  8 <NA>
#6       2 2000 NA NA <NA>
#7       2 2000 NA NA <NA>
#8       2 2002 NA NA <NA>
#9       2 2002 NA NA <NA>
#10      2 2003 NA NA <NA>
```

You may indeed want to take a `dplyr::mutate()` approach (base is cumbersome here), using either `.by = c(firmid, year)` for newer versions (as below) or `... %>% group_by(firmid, year) %>% mutate(...)` for previous versions:

```
df %>%
  mutate(non_missing_columns = sum(rowSums(!is.na(across(everything())))),
         .by = c(firmid, year))

#   firmid year c1 c2   cn non_missing_columns
#1       1 2000 NA  4 text                   5
#2       1 2000  3  2 text                   5
#3       1 2002 NA NA <NA>                   2
#4       1 2002  2  3 <NA>                   2
#5       1 2003 NA  8 <NA>                   1
#6       2 2000 NA NA <NA>                   0
#7       2 2000 NA NA <NA>                   0
#8       2 2002 NA NA <NA>                   0
#9       2 2002 NA NA <NA>                   0
#10      2 2003 NA NA <NA>                   0
```

You can check/see what it's doing by adding in a few other columns just to check it is properly summing by group (the `non_missing_columns` should equal the sum of `individual_missing` for each `group_no`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(non_missing_columns = sum(rowSums(!is.na(across(everything())))),
         group_no = cur_group_id(),
         .by = c(firmid, year)) %>%
  mutate(individual_missing = rowSums(!is.na(across(starts_with("c")))))

   firmid year c1 c2   cn non_missing_columns group_no individual_missing
#1       1 2000 NA  4 text                   5        1                  2
#2       1 2000  3  2 text                   5        1                  3
#3       1 2002 NA NA <NA>                   2        2                  0
#4       1 2002  2  3 <NA>                   2        2                  2
#5       1 2003 NA  8 <NA>                   1        3                  1
#6       2 2000 NA NA <NA>                   0        4                  0
#7       2 2000 NA NA <NA>                   0        4                  0
#8       2 2002 NA NA <NA>                   0        5                  0
#9       2 2002 NA NA <NA>                   0        5                  0
#10      2 2003 NA NA <NA>                   0        6                  0
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
df |> dplyr::mutate(nonmissingcolumns = rowSums(!is.na(across(everything()))))
```

The issues with your code are:

1. `non-missing-columns` is evaluated to be be `non` minus `missing` minus `columns`. Add ticks around it (`non-missing-columns`) or replace the dashes with underscores
2. The `.` in `sum(!is.na(.)))` is the dataframe, so each value is the number of non-NA values in the whole dataframe (i.e. 18)